# How to store a pdf file in downloads folder

Tags: java, android, kotlin, pdf-generation, android-11

I have made an application which capture images through camera and convert them into pdf file. Now the problem is that the pdf is getting stored in my app data as according to latest storage update in android 11 we can't make new folder outside the app data. So now I want to store my pdf file into Downloads folder which comes under shared storage so that it doesn't delete if I uninstall the app. Here is the code through which I was storing the pdf file in app's data:

```
private fun CreatePdf(list: ArrayList<Bitmap>){

    val file: File?=getOutputFile()
    if (file != null) {
        try {
            val fileOutputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
            val document = PDDocument()
            for(i in 0 until list.size) {
                val page = PDPage(A4)
                document.addPage(page)
                val contentStream = PDPageContentStream(document, page)

                val ximage = JPEGFactory.createFromImage(document, list[i], 1f)

                contentStream.drawImage(ximage, 0f, 0f)

                contentStream.close()
            }
            document.save(fileOutputStream)
            document.close()

        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

}


private fun getOutputFile(): File?{
    val root: File = File(getExternalFilesDir(null),"my file")

    var isFolderCreated = true

    if (!root.exists()) {
        isFolderCreated = root.mkdir()
    }

    return if (isFolderCreated) {
        val timeStamp: String = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.US).format(Date())
        val imageFileName = "PDF_$timeStamp"
        File(root, "$imageFileName.pdf")
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Folder is not created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        null
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes.. you are storing.. and now.. what is the question?

Comment: The qus is how do I store it in downloads so that when I uninstall the application it doesn't delete the Pdf files.

Comment: Your code is ok. You can use the same code. You only have to use a different path. A path to the Downloads folder.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the concept of SAF. But I just want to save it in downloads can you please guide me in it. I edited the subject of question.

Comment: `I just want to save it in downloads` ? What is downloads? There is a only a Download folder. I already guided you. Use a path to the Download folder instead of to getExternalFilesDir. Thats all.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
var relativePath = Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS
if (hasSubFolder) {
    relativePath += File.separator + yourSubFolderName
}
val fileName: String = yourFileName
val values = ContentValues()
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName)
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, relativePath)
val cr = context.contentResolver
val uri = cr.insert(MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values)
uri?.let {
    val outputStream = cr.openOutputStream(uri)
    document.save(outputStream)
}
```

Comment: How do you check if saving was a success or not.

Comment: @Hope saving success if no excepetion occur